# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException on InjectMocks object

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to mock the return value from a method but I'm getting `NotAMockException`.

```
@InjectMocks
private MyService myService;
@Mock
private OtherServiceUsedInMyServiceAsAutowired otherServiceUsedInMyServiceAsAutowired;
```

Inside `MyService` I have a method called `myMethod()` and I want to return dummy object when this method is called.

```
doReturn(someDummyObject).when(myService).myMethod(any(), any(), any());
```

And at that point I'm getting the error. What am I doing wrong? Full error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

Comment: is the @InjectMocks annotation actually creating a mock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotation [`@InjectMocks`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#21) is used to inject mocks into a tested object:

> `@InjectMocks` - injects mocks into tested object automatically.

It does not mean that object will be a mock itself. This annotation is useful if you want to test an object and want that object to have pre-initialized mock instances automatically (through setter injection).

If you want to create a mock of `MyService`, use `@Mock`:

```
@Mock
private MyService myService;
```

This will create a mock of `MyService` and you will need to specify the behaviour you want for that mock. The first thing is that `OtherServiceUsedInMyServiceAsAutowired` does not make sense anymore: the mocked object won't depend on that class.

Comment: If I use @Mock for MyService, will that also autowire the mocked OtherServiceUsedInMyServiceAsAutowired ?

Comment: @AntonBelev I think you are misunderstanding what a mock is. There are no autowiring inside a mock. You control the mock by calling the `do...` methods or `when`.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I was using InjectMocks was because I had an Autowired filed inside the MyService and I wanted this field to be initialized with a mock object thus the Mock. However I didn't know that InjectMocks is not creating a mock.